# show a new view after x seconds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm quite new to Objective-C and I have this problem.
I'm animating an image an show this in a imageview.
after 15 seconds i want to show another view, thought of a "flying in view from the bottom".

Any hints for me how i could manage that?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), it lets you call a delegate after a certain time. Views can be animated to come in from the bottom as well by using UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp. Check out the [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) doc for more information and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way is to call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`